# IIFE run Function Declaration and Function Expression with different result

Tags: javascript, function, closures, hosting

I try use Immediately-Invoked Function Expression to running another function.
If I use FE, it turns out an error

```js
let f = function(x) {
  alert(x)
}

(function() {
  f(1)
}())
// ReferenceError: Cannot access 'f' before initialization
```

Using FD it works:

```js
function f(x) {
  alert(x)
}

(function() {
  f(1)
}())
// 1
```

What is going on inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause a *function declaration* cannot be directly called, thats why the `(...)` after it is parsed as a seperate statement.

You never end the variable declaration containing the *function expression* with an `;`, therefore the following parentheses are a function call:

```
 let f = function() { /*...*/ }(/*...*/)(/*...*/);
```

TLDR: Always end statements with semicolons.

```
 let f = function() { /*...*/ }; // <<<
```